# Numeric Field with multivalue in XPages

Tags: xpages

I have a numeric field which has multivalue. I set values of numeric field in backend. I try to show values line by line in a Dojo Text Area. But my problem starts here. When open document in edit Mode. `djTextBox` adds "." and one decimal place (Zero "0") (added screenshot below). How can i make it to show only the original value of field without adding any dot(".") or Zero("0"). If it not possible I can change the way it did.

```
<xe:djTextarea id="CountHID" value="#{document1.CountH}" multipleSeparator="#{javascript:@NewLine();}">
<xe:this.converter>
```

[image: DjTextBox]

Answer (score 2):

When stored / edited by default in XPages numbers are Doubles. So because a Double includes decimal content, that's why the decimal is showing. You need to set the display type to Number and Integer Only (on Data tab of the Properties pretty panel).

Source pane XML markup for this is:

```
<xp:this.converter>
    <xp:convertNumber type="number" integerOnly="true"></xp:convertNumber>
</xp:this.converter>
```